# Proportionality in ILOG CPLEX

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ilog

I am trying to include proportionality in my solution.
The .dat is as follows:

```
Farms = {Rice,Barns,Snyder};
Crops = {Corn,Wheat,SoyBeans};
UsableLand = [400,600,300];
Water = [600,800,375];
MaximumQuota = [600,500,325];
WaterConsumption = [3,2,1];
Profit = [1000,750,250];
```

My .mod is currently built as follows:

```
{string} Farms = ...;
{string} Crops = ...;

int UsableLand[Farms]=...;
int Water[Farms]=...;
int MaximumQuota[Crops]=...;
int WaterConsumption[Crops]=...;
int Profit[Crops]=...;

constraint LandAcre[Farms];
constraint WaterAcre[Farms];
constraint CropLimit[Crops];
constraint Propotionality[Crops][Farms];

dvar float+ ProductionAmount[Crops][Farms];

maximize
  sum(i in Crops)
    sum(j in Farms)
    Profit[i]*ProductionAmount[i][j];
        
subject to {
  forall(j in Farms)
    LandAcre[j]:
        sum(i in Crops)   ProductionAmount[i][j] <= UsableLand[j];   
  forall(j in Farms)
    WaterAcre[j]:
        sum(i in Crops)   WaterConsumption[i] * ProductionAmount[i][j] <= Water[j]; 
  forall(i in Crops)
    CropLimit[i]:
        sum(j in Farms)   ProductionAmount[i][j] <= MaximumQuota[i];
```

My question is how to include proportionality as a constraint.  Do I add such as:

```
  forall(j in Farms)
    Proportionality [j]:
        sum(i in Crops)   ProductionAmount[i][j] / UsableLand[j] == ProductionAmount[i][j] / UsableLand[j];
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
dvar float ratio[Crops] in 0..1;
```

and then write

```
forall(j in Farms)
    Proportionality :
         forall(i in Crops)ProductionAmount[i][j] / UsableLand[j] == ratio[i];
```

You entire .mod would then be

```
{string} Farms = ...;
{string} Crops = ...;

int UsableLand[Farms]=...;
int Water[Farms]=...;
int MaximumQuota[Crops]=...;
int WaterConsumption[Crops]=...;
int Profit[Crops]=...;

constraint LandAcre[Farms];
constraint WaterAcre[Farms];
constraint CropLimit[Crops];
//constraint Propotionality[Crops][Farms];

dvar float+ ProductionAmount[Crops][Farms];
dvar float ratio[Crops] in 0..1;

maximize
  sum(i in Crops)
    sum(j in Farms)
    Profit[i]*ProductionAmount[i][j];
        
subject to {
  forall(j in Farms)
    LandAcre[j]:
        sum(i in Crops)   ProductionAmount[i][j] <= UsableLand[j];   
  forall(j in Farms)
    WaterAcre[j]:
        sum(i in Crops)   WaterConsumption[i] * ProductionAmount[i][j] <= Water[j]; 
  forall(i in Crops)
    CropLimit[i]:
        sum(j in Farms)   ProductionAmount[i][j] <= MaximumQuota[i];
        
   forall(j in Farms)
    Proportionality :
         forall(i in Crops)ProductionAmount[i][j] / UsableLand[j] == ratio[i];    
        
        
        
      }
```